# Webscraping R script doesn't run from crontab

Tags: r, web-scraping, cron, reddit

I'm having issues running a R script that scrapes posts from Reddit as a cron job. The script works flawlessly when manually sourced from within R. Other R scripts also run fine from the crontab. Also, the R scraping package is specifically built to not overrun the Reddit API.

crontab:

```
*/25 * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript "home/ubuntu/cryptoAPI/NLP/NLPupdater.R"
```

R script:

```
setwd("/home/ubuntu/cryptoAPI/NLP")
library(RedditExtractoR)#install.packages('RedditExtractoR')
library('httr')
library(data.table)

#1. check for most recent reddit urls
ss.new.Reddit <- fileSnapshot(path="/home/ubuntu/cryptoAPI/NLP/raw", file.info = F)
Reddit.num <- nrow(ss.new.Reddit[[1]])-1

#2. load CCtop100 snapshot from cronjob
Reddit.urls <- rjson::fromJSON(file=paste0('raw/hot.json@limit=50.', Reddit.num))#"raw/hot.json@limit=100.", Reddit.num))

#3. extract urls from list
urlvector <- character(50)    #to 100
for(i in 1:52){               #also to 102
  urlvector[i] <- Reddit.urls$`data`$children[[i]]$data$permalink }

#4. combine w formatting for reddict extractor # add 'http://www.reddit.com'
urlvector.long <- paste0('http://www.reddit.com', urlvector)

#5. run redditextractor
Reddit.comments <- reddit_content(urlvector.long)

#6. save new csv
NLPcsv <- paste0("CSV/reddit-nlp-",Reddit.num,".csv" )
fwrite(Reddit.comments, file=NLPcsv)
fwrite(Reddit.comments, file='current/currentNLP.csv')
```

Is there some limit on how long a cronjob can take? The scrape takes maybe 3mins to complete.

Comment: Are you intentionally omitting the leading slash in `"home/ubuntu/cr..."` in the crontab entry?

Comment: Hmmm, no, good catch, lemme update that and see how it goes

Comment: It should have run twice by now (judging by `*/25`), did changing the crontab path fix it?

Comment: It checks every 25mins, but there's only new snapshot every hour. I manually reran the last one, so have to wait until next hour comes in (should be soon...). The snapshot might have been already updated for the past hour

Comment: Yes! Looks like it's working! I thought someone asked but it's a data dashboard for tracking cryptocurrencies. Basically has 3 parts: API calls to exchanges to obtain data every 5mins, including transformations for certain moving averages and weighted adjustments, sentiment analysis and content from hourly reddit posts and a variety of machine learning algorithms for predicting 24hr and eventually 7d timesteps.

Comment: Ok, so fixing the typo is key. I think you have two possible actions with this question: (a) delete it, as the problem was a simple typo (and keeping it here will not likely help others); or (b) answer it yourself and "accept" the answer (to close it out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the cronjob, forgot a / in the path:

```
*/25 * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript "/home/ubuntu/cryptoAPI/NLP/NLPupdater.R"
```